# Batch file to open X number of files in a folder

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am writing a batch file.

In the middle of the batch file I would like to have it open 2 files in the folder.  Doesn't matter which one.. could be the first two, last two, whatever.  I am doing this so our users can check some images in a book through a longer batch file process.  I would like to do something like this:

```
set book=12345
for /F in ('\\server\share\%book%\*.pdf') DO (
open the first PDF file in the folder
)
Repeat one time
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could track the number of iterations and exit the loop when you've hit your limit.

```
:: Enable delayedexpansion so we can use variables in the for loop
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set book=12345
set count=0
for %%F in (*.pdf) DO (
    REM - open the PDF file here

    :: Increment count (/a does arithmetic addition)
    set /a count=!count!+1

    :: Exit loop if count is 2
    if !count! == 2 goto after
)

:after
```